Finding the eigenvalues of a $4\times 4$ symmetric matrix
Given the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1+r}{4} & 0 & 0 & \frac{r}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{1-r}{4} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1-r}{4} & 0 \\ \frac{r}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1+r}{4} \end{bmatrix}$$
where $0\leq r \leq 1$.
How can I find the eigenvalues of the matrix?
Can I permute it to be a block matrix of $$A = \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & E \end{bmatrix}$$ somehow and then find the eigen values of $B$ and $E$?

The permutation approach is possible. Consider the slightly more general  matrix (it is easier to type)
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a &   &   & b\\
  & c\\
  &   & d\\
b &   &   & a
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Empty entries are zeros.
Then the conjugation with the permutation matrix $S$ that brings the
last row/column on the second position,
$$
S=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
  &  & & 1\\
  & 1  \\
  &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\ ,
$$
conjugates $A$ in a block matrix:
$$
SAS^{-1}
=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
b & a\\
  &   & c\\
  &   &   & d
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Then $A$ and $SAS^{-1}$ have the same eigenvalues (with eigenvectors corresponding to each other via multiplication by $S$ or $S^{-1}$), and two eigenvalues of $SAS^{-1}$ are optically on the diagonal. The other two come from the first $2\times 2$ block. It remains to see what happens in the given situation (with the special value of $a,b,c,d$).

Good idea and throrough sober presentation.

Thank you, such a an intuitive and simple explanation.

Yes, you can triangularize, add a multiple of the last row to the first row, and the characteristic polynomial then is given by
$$
\chi(x)=-\frac{1}{256}(3r - 4x + 1)(r + 4x - 1)^3.
$$
So the eigenvalues are $(3r+1)/4$ and $(1-r)/4$.

What do you mean by "add a multiple of the last row to the first row" ? could you show me in mathematical notation ? (sorry, English is not my native language)

The determinant is multilinear, so you can change a row or column vector by adding a scalar multiple of another row or column. It is easy to obtain a triangular matrix, where the eigenvalues are already on the diagonal.

One can notice that
$$V_1=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\1} \ \text{and} \ V_2=\pmatrix{0\\1\\1\\0}$$
are eigenvectors because :
$$AV_1=\frac{1+3r}{4}V_1  \ \text{and} \ AV_2=\frac{1-r}{4}V_2$$
therefore with associated eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\frac{1+3r}{4}$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{1-r}{4}.$
In fact, eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ has multiplicity $3$ because :
$$A-\lambda_2 I = \pmatrix{(\frac{1+r}{4}-\frac{1-r}{4}) & 0 & 0 & \frac{r}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{r}{2} & 0 & 0 & (\frac{1+r}{4}-\frac{1-r}{4})}=\pmatrix{\frac{r}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{r}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{r}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{r}{2}}$$
has rank $1$ only. It means that its kernel has dimension $4-1=3$ ; therefore the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ has ($\textit{geometric}$ multiplicity $3$.
As a consequence, the spectrum of $A$ is necessarily :
$$\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_2, \lambda_2.$$
due to the fact that the $\textit{algebraic}$ multiplicity of an eigenvalue (i.e., its multiplicity  in the characteristic polynomial) is always greater or equal to its $\textit{geometric}$ multiplicity.

See for example an analogous solution here

A variation on this same approach is to note $A=\frac{1-r}{4} I+\frac{r}{2}V_1V_1^\top$. Hence one eigenvector is $V_1$ itself, with the other three spanning the orthogonal complement of $V_1$.

@Semiclassical Very interesting comment ! Rank-one updating, once more... You should give it as an answer.

Thank you so much, both you and @dan_fulea answers were really helpful !
